# Assign event to technician

Tags: optaplanner

I am using optaplanner.I have One technician and 3 events .Technician working time is morning 8 to evening 6 ,1st event start time is 10 am and 2nd event time is 11am and 3rd event time is 9am to 1pm between,all event duration is 30 minitus .So my problem is how can assign and calculate best score for technician in time range .
i want  3rd event assigned technician 9 to 9.3o and 1st event aasigned 10 am and 2nd event aasigned 11am.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your story here - but we are expecting questions describing a specific issue related to your code

Answer (score 0):

The best way to define your score funcion is to take this input problem and put a number of possible resulting states on paper (preferably in a spreadsheet). Then figure out a way to score those different combinations such as the "best solution" has the best score. For example by doing load balancing (= **see docs section "fairness"**) of the gaps between 2 starting time.